# Loop thru line breaks and count lines?

Tags: php

I have a string such as the one below.  I want to loop thru each line (lines are separated by `<br />`) and count total lines.  How can I do this?

```
This is line 1 <br />
And Line 2 <br />
And and line 3! <br />
```

My output should be 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
$lines = explode( '<br />', $string);
array_pop( $lines); // Remove the last element
foreach( $lines as $line) {
    $i++;
}
echo $i;
```

However, you don't need the loop, you can just call [`count()`](http://php.net/count) after the call to [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/array_pop):

```
echo count( $lines);
```

Note that I added the call to [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/array_pop) because you have a trailing `<br />`, which will cause the array created from [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to have an empty last element. So I remove it.

Comment: Still waiting for a comment downvoters... OP: **I want to loop thru each line and count total lines.** Seems pretty straightforward to me...

Comment: Just FYI, the overhead on **[this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NZsvkf)** is double that of the **[substr_count](http://codepad.viper-7.com/U5XEJB)** method.

Answer (score 5):

```
// count the number of times <br /> occurs in the string
substr_count( $your_string, "<br />" );
```